# AngularJS function to filter data

Tags: angularjs

I have a column in mysql database called date and each posts have a different date like: 2015-1-1
I have created a function to check if today's date matches the date in the mysql db so it filters the post by date.

Here is my app.js

```
  app.controller('TimeController', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.post('ajax/getQuotes.php').success(function(data){

         $scope.quote = filterByDate(data);

      });


      function filterByDate(input) {
          var date = new Date();

          var day = date.getDate();
          var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
          var year = date.getFullYear();
          var matchDate = year + "-" + day+ "-" + month;
          if( input[value] == matchDate){
              return data; 
          }


      }
```

But this is not working, any advise?

Comment: what are you returning here? this code looks like it doesn't really do anything at all

Answer (score 0):

Two questions :

1. Why are you pulling all the data first and then applying you filter? Why not limit you request to the date you want on the server side and only return the data for that date?
2. If you want to pull all the data at once, use the filter within your ng-repeat. That way you data is dynamic and you can still change the filter afterwards.

Comment: Hi Michael! Thank you. 1. I was told it is possible to filter on server side but I would need to pass some kind of variable in the url like: /?month=1, I did some google search and could not get it to work. 2. I could use ng-repeat, but I tried my code to filter both month & days but could not get this to work either, please let me know if you need more infos?

Answer (score 0):

Your filter code doesn't make any sense.

1. You accept a variable named `input`.
2. You create a new `date` object with today's date.
3. You set the `day`, `month`, and `year` variables to the day a month from today.
4. You manually build a string called `matchDate` based on the `year`, `day`, and `month` values.
5. you try to compare your `matchDate` variable to an array index on your `input`, using a variable that was never defined called `value`.  This will never evaluate to `true`, for a few reasons, most specifically because `input[value]` makes no sense. Also, you should use `===` instead of `==`.
6. If, somehow, your comparison were to evaluate to `true`, you attempt to return a variable called `data` which is never defined within the function, so is most certainly `null`.